# Passing arguments into the revealing Module pattern in Javascript

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, revealing-module-pattern

How can you pass arguments to a function when implementing the Revealing module pattern in JavaScript. I have a module like this

```
var GlobalModule = (function() {
    function consoleLog(textToOutput) {
        console.log(textToOutput);
    }

    return {
        consoleLog: consoleLog()
    };
})();
```

Later on, when i run `GlobalModule.consoleLog("Dummy text");`, I get `undefined` as the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do with function inside the return object

```js
var GlobalModule = (function() {
  return {
    consoleLog: function(textToOutput)
    {
     console.log(textToOutput);
    }
  }
})();

GlobalModule.consoleLog("Dummy text");
```

Simply Do like this same output achieved . `object => function call` .No need a return object

```js
 var GlobalModule ={
        consoleLog: function(textToOutput) {
                                    console.log(textToOutput);
                                  }
      }

    GlobalModule.consoleLog("Dummy text");
```

Comment: but what if you don't want to invoke a method or property of the module, i.e. i want to do `myRevealingModule('my-string')`, and not  `myRevealingModule.doSomething('my-string')`.

Comment: @RonRoyston you need a direct function call.[see this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/poosanth/coshzhra/)

Answer (score 4):

```
return {
    consoleLog: consoleLog()
};
```

That part of your code is wrong.
You're exporting the Result of the consoleLog call due to the () at the end of the function, where you want to export the function itsself.
So just remove the function call:

```
return {
    consoleLog: consoleLog
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the line

```
consoleLog: consoleLog()
```

To

```
consoleLog: consoleLog
```

Or even(es6) to:

```
consoleLog
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this

```
var GlobalModule = (function() {
    function consoleLog(textToOutput) {
        console.log(textToOutput);
    }

    return {
        consoleLog: consoleLog // () is removed otherwise it will execute immediately
    };
})();

GlobalModule.consoleLog('Hello')
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/qpwdecdj/)

You you want to pass a global variable pass it in the parenthesis of the IIFE

```
var GlobalModule = (function(x) {
    function consoleLog(textToOutput) {
        console.log(textToOutput,x); // will log Hello temp
    }
   return {
        consoleLog: consoleLog
    };
})('temp');
```